# Backing up data on your Google mail account in Android

Tags: android, gmail

I want to have my application periodically save a zip file to the cloud.

Since I don't want to set my own cloud solution, I thought of doing something similar to what the application [SMS Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tv.studer.smssync) does. It saves your Gmail credentials and when a new sms arrives it saves it to your Gmail under a specified Label and also marks it as read.

Now, I know how to send email from Java programmaticaly. My question is how to access Gmail only features such as assigning labels to the message and marking it as read. I imagine there must be some facilities built in to Android to allow you to manipulate the GMail account linked to the phone am i right?

Comment: Require dropbox and save it to a dropbox account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest versions of Android, Google provides a much more elegant and integrated solution in the form of the built-in data backup which apps can use. Documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

Answer (score 0):

> I imagine there must be some
>   facilities built in to Android to
>   allow you to manipulate the GMail
>   account linked to the phone am i
>   right?

Sorry, GMail has no public API in the SDK.